# Pointer to a nested list element

Tags: r

Take the following list:

```
lst <- list(a = 1, b = list(c = 2, d = 3))
```

Now I would like to have a pointer to the `d` element so that when I update its value, it is reflected in the original list. E.g.:

```
d <- lst[['b']][['d']] # d should be a reference.
update(d, 5) # custom function for updating by reference.
lst[['b']][['d']]
#> [1] 5
```

Why do I want this? Because I do all kinds of updates on lists several levels deep, which results in tedious code similar to the following:

```
lst[['b']][['d']] <- some_function(lst[['b']][['d']], lst[['b']][['c']])
```

So I wonder if there are any idioms in R which would make the code more concise and readable?

Comment: Not sure if you need `assign_in(lst, list('b', 'd'), 3)`

Comment: @akrun, the `update()` function will update the value where `d` points to. Pointer `d` should point to `lst[['b']][['d']]`

Comment: I guess the `assign_in` or `modify_in` from NelsonGon would make it easier

Comment: Interesting functions! On first sight, it seems that they could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We could make use of `assign_in` from `purrr` if we can provide the names or index of the nested `list`

```
library(purrr)
assign_in(lst, list('b', 'd'), 5)
#$a
#[1] 1

#$b
#$b$c
#[1] 2

#$b$d
#[1] 5
```

Or with `magrittr` to update the original object

```
library(magrittr)
lst %<>%
   assign_in(list('b', 'd'), 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base`-`purrr` solution not tested on very deep lists:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) purrr::modify_at(x,2,function(x) 5))
```

Or as suggested by @akrun, `modify_in` that negates the need for `lapply`:

```
modify_in(lst, list('b', 'd'), ~ 5)
```

Result:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
$b$c
[1] 2

$b$d
[1] 5
```

Comment: You could use `modify_in` as well `modify_in(lst, list('b', 'd'), ~ 5)`